# Multiplication of three integers in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, multiplication

I want to multiply three integers in MIPS. My first thought was to multiply the first and the second one, and after that the result with the third one (like I did it with add). But the result is given in `HI` and `LOW` in 64-bit. So how can I multiply it with the third factor?

And: *32-bit integer * 32-bit integer = 64-bit integer*. What (in the theory) would give that:

> *32-bit int * 32-bit int * 32-bit int = ??*

96-bit? 128?

Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying an n-bit number with an m-bit number produces a (n+m) bit number.
So multiplying three 32-bit numbers produces a 96-bit product

Suppose the three numbers are a, b and c, we have the following result

```
  a*b  =   ABH*2³² + ABL
c(a*b) = c(ABH*2³² + ABL)
       = c*ABH*2³² + c*ABL
       = (CABH_H*2³² + CABH_L)*2³² + (CABL_H*2³² + CABL_L)
       = CABH_H*2⁶⁴ + (CABH_L + CABL_H)*2³² + CABL_L
```

where H and L are the high and low parts of the result which are stored in the HI and LO registers respectively. Here the multiplications by 2<sup>32</sup> and 2<sup>64</sup> will be replaced by shifting left by 32 and 64 respectively.

So in MIPS32 if a, b and c are stored in $s0, $s1 and $s2 we can do the math as below

```
multu   $s0, $s1        # (HI, LO) = a*b
mfhi    $t0             # t0 = ABH
mflo    $t1             # t1 = ABL

multu   $s2, $t1        # (HI, LO) = c*ABL
mfhi    $t4             # t4 = CABL_H
mflo    $s7             # s7 = CABL_L

multu   $s2, $t0        # (HI, LO) = c*ABH
mfhi    $s5             # s5 = CABH_H
mflo    $t3             # t3 = CABH_L

addu    $s6, $t3, $t4   # s6 = CABH_L + CABL_H
sltu    $t5, $s6, $t3   # carry if s6 overflows
addu    $s5, $s5, $t5   # add carry to s5
# result = (s5 << 64) | (s6 << 32) | s7
```

The result is stored in the tuple ($s5, $s6, $s7)

Things will be much simpler in MIPS64:

```
mul(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int):
        multu   $4,$5
        dext    $6,$6,0,32
        mfhi    $3
        mflo    $2
        dins    $2,$3,32,32
        dmultu  $6,$2
        mflo    $3
        j       $31
        mfhi    $2
```

Here's some sample assembly output from [GCC on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0Aunsigned+__int128+mul1(uint32_t+a,+uint32_t+b,+uint32_t+c)%0A%7B%0A++++return+(unsigned+__int128)((uint64_t)a*b)*c%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:58.333333333333336,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips564,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'MIPS64+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:48.24561403508772,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0Astruct+i128+%7B+uint32_t+H,+M,+L%3B+%7D%3B%0Ai128+mul2(uint32_t+a,+uint32_t+b,+uint32_t+c)%0A%7B%0A++++const+uint64_t+LOW_MASK+%3D+0xFFFFFFFFull%3B%0A++++i128+result%3B%0A++++//+calculate+CABH_H*2%E2%81%B6%E2%81%B4+%2B+(CABH_L+%2B+CABL_H)*2%C2%B3%C2%B2+%2B+CABL_L%0A++++uint64_t+AB+++%3D+(uint64_t)a*b%3B%0A++++uint64_t+CABL+%3D+(AB+%26+LOW_MASK)*c%3B%0A++++uint64_t+CABH+%3D+(AB+%3E%3E+32)*c%3B%0A++++%0A++++result.L+%3D+CABL+%26+LOW_MASK%3B%0A++++result.M+%3D+(CABL+%3E%3E+32)+%2B+(CABH+%26+LOW_MASK)%3B%0A++++result.H+%3D+(CABH+%3E%3E+32)+%2B+(result.M+%3C+(CABH+%26+LOW_MASK))%3B%0A++++return+result%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%232',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:41.66666666666667,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips5,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:2),l:'5',n:'0',o:'MIPS+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%232,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:51.75438596491229,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),k:100,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

You may need some slight modification for signed operations