# MIPS32 Multiplication of Three 32-bit Integers

Tags: mips32

I am trying to write a MIPS32 program that will multiply three numbers together. For example: (A * B * C) where A, B, and C are 32 bit signed numbers.

I know from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050338/mips-integer-multiplication-and-division) that I need to do the following to multiply A*B (assume A is stored in $s0, B is stored in $s1, and C is stored in $2):

```
mult $s0, $s1
mfhi $t0
mflo $t1
```

If I am assuming my result of the multiplication of A * B is 64 bits, how do I calculate the result of (A * B) with C?

Comment: Do you want the full 96 bit result?

Comment: Yes I want the full 96 bit result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MIPS - multiplication of three integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650416/mips-multiplication-of-three-integers)